# PHP - use of variable

Tags: php, variables

I want my PHP code to display one out of N .txt files on my webpage. (If I visit example.com/index.php?l=1 it should display 1.txt) I´m using a variable for the numbers called $m. $m is defined correctly as it is working on other pages.

My problem is that I can´t define the location of "1.txt" with a variable. My code is:

```
    $filename = "C:\xampp\project\Logs\.$m.'.txt';
                if (file_exists($filename)) {
                    if (is_readable($filename)) {
                        $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
                        if (filesize($filename) > 0) {
                            $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
                            fclose($handle);
                            $contents = str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $contents);


                            echo ' <textarea data-autoresize class="form-control vresize" id="info" rows="20">'.$contents.'</textarea>';    
                        } else {
                             echo ' <textarea data-autoresize class="form-control vresize" id="info" rows="20"></textarea>'; 
                        }    
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<br><font color=red>Cant get any Logs for ID: '.$m.'</font>';
                }
```

I tried a few different things but nothing worked out for me because $m does not get resolved in $filename.

Was anybody able to follow my description and understands my problem? Help is very appreciated!

Comment: there's a syntax error in your code. Stack's syntax highlighting is showing you.

Comment: Change your first row to :
"C:\xampp\project\Logs\".$m.'.txt';

Comment: Alredy tried:

        Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR)

If I add another " to fix the syntax error I get "Can´t get any Logs for ID: 1234567890"

Comment: @Fred: Syntax error fixed, still getting "Can´t get any Logs for ID: 1234567890" even though 1234567890.txt exists and is in the right folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$filename = 'C:/xampp/project/Logs/' . $m . '.txt';
```

You had mismatched quotes. I've also changed the backslashes to forward slashes, because backslashes have special meaning in PHP strings; Windows allows either style to be used in pathnames.

Comment: First of all thanks for helping. Unfortunately, your code gives me "Can´t get any Logs for ID: 1234567890" error even though 1234567890.txt is in the correct folder

Are you sure it should be working with this code? If yes, I´m looking for the mistake at the wrong end ...

Thanks again

Comment: Can you show an actual filename. I wasn't sure which dots in your code were part of the filename or PHP concatenation operators.

Comment: Is it `Logs.123456.txt` or `Logs123456.txt`?

Comment: I just fixed it by myself:
$filename = 'C:/xampp/project/Logs/'.$m . '.txt';
is working. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it!